# Beginner Python-Looping to the beginning of a programme

Tags: python, while-loop

I will start fresh! I have included the full code so you can get a picture for what i am trying to do. Prob (1) I can not loop back to the very beginning. Prob (2) It is not looping @ the While higher_or_lower part of the code. it just goes through the if and else higher_or_lower statements. Thanks

```
done = False

while done == False:

    import random


    def is_same(targ, num):
        if targ == num:
            result="WIN"
        elif targ > num:
            result="LOW"
        else:
            result="HIGH"
            return result



    User_Name = input("What is your name?\n:")
    print("\nWelcome", User_Name, "To the guessing number game")
    print( """\n\n
                GUESSING NUMBER GAME
          ----------------------------------
          ##################################
          #                                #
          #     [E] For Easy 1 - 10        #
          #                                #
          #     [M] For Medium 1 - 50      #
          #                                #
          #     [H] For Hard 1 - 100       #
          #                                #
          ##################################
          """ )

    Choose_Level = input("\t\tPlease choose your Level : " )


    while Choose_Level != "E" and Choose_Level != "M" and Choose_Level != "H":
        Choose_Level = input("Sorry. You must type in one of the letters 'E', 'M', 'H'\n:")


    if Choose_Level == "E":
        print("You have chosen the Easy Level! You are a wimp by nature")
    elif Choose_Level == "M":
        print("You have chosen the Medium Level! Can you defeat the game?")
    else:
        print("You have chosen the Hard Level! You are a Guessing Number warrior")


    if Choose_Level == "E":
        computer_number = random.randint(1,10)
    elif Choose_Level == "M":
        computer_number = random.randint(1,50)
    else:
        computer_number = random.randint(1,100) 


    guess = int(input("Can you guess the number? \n:"))




    higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)

    counter = 1


    while higher_or_lower != "WIN":
        counter +=1
        if higher_or_lower == "LOW":
            print("Guess attempts", counter)
            guess = int(input("\nSorry, you are to low. Please try again.\n:"))
        else:
            print("Guess attempts", counter)
            guess = int(input("\nSorry, To high. Please try again. \n:"))
            higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
            input("Correct!\nWell done\n\n")
            print( """
            ##############################
            #                            #
            #    [S] Play again          #
            #                            #
            #    [E] Exit                #
            #                            #
            ##############################
            """)

            start_again = (input("\t\t Please choose a option 'S' or 'E' "))


            while start_again != "S" and start_again != "E":
                start_again = (input("You must enter a upper case letter 'S' or 'E' to continue"))

            if start_again == "S":
                done = False
            else:

                print("Thanks for playing the number game. Goodbye")
                done = True
                breaK
```

Comment: Why do you do this? done = False while done == False: import random

Why not just "import random"?

Comment: return is part of the else block because it is indented too far.

Comment: Trim your code and explanation down. Right now I see a huge wall of text and a mess of code, and don't know what your exact question is.

Comment: It printed out like that i dont know why

Comment: Please start with a simple example rather than this huge code then you can understand the identation stuff prior to asking question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like adding a little structure would help you out.

Something like this might help you with doing your control flow.  Hopefully gives you an outline that makes sense and makes it easier to run the loop multiple times.

```
""" Guess the number game.
"""
import random


def is_same(targ, num):
    """ Check for correct entry. """
    if targ == num:
        result = "WIN"
    elif targ > num:
        result = "LOW"
    else:
        result = "HIGH"

    return result


def play_game():
    """ Play the game 1 time, returns play_again """
    User_Name = input("What is your name?\n:")
    print("\nWelcome", User_Name, "To the guessing number game")
    print("""\n\n
                GUESSING NUMBER GAME
          ----------------------------------
          ##################################
          #                                #
          #     [E] For Easy 1 - 10        #
          #                                #
          #     [M] For Medium 1 - 50      #
          #                                #
          #     [H] For Hard 1 - 100       #
          #                                #
          ##################################
          """)

    Choose_Level = input("\t\tPlease choose your Level : ")

    while Choose_Level != "E" and Choose_Level != "M" and Choose_Level != "H":
        # this could be simplified to: while choose_level not in 'EMF':
        Choose_Level = input("Sorry. You must type in one of the letters " +
                "'E', 'M', 'H'\n:")

    if Choose_Level == "E":
        print("You have chosen the Easy Level! You are a wimp by nature")
    elif Choose_Level == "M":
        print("You have chosen the Medium Level! Can you defeat the game?")
    else:
        print("You have chosen the Hard Level! " +
                "You are a Guessing Number warrior")

    if Choose_Level == "E":
        computer_number = random.randint(1, 10)
    elif Choose_Level == "M":
        computer_number = random.randint(1, 50)
    else:
        computer_number = random.randint(1, 100)

    counter = 1
    higher_or_lower = ""
    while higher_or_lower != "WIN":
        guess = int(input("Can you guess the number? \n:"))
        higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)
        counter += 1

        if higher_or_lower == "LOW":
            print("Guess attempts", counter)
            print("\nSorry, you are to low. Please try again.\n:")
        elif higher_or_lower == "HIGH":
            print("Guess attempts", counter)
            print("\nSorry, To high. Please try again. \n:")
        else:
            print("Correct!\nWell done\n\n")
            break

    print("""
    ##############################
    #                            #
    #    [S] Play again          #
    #                            #
    #    [E] Exit                #
    #                            #
    ##############################
    """)

    start_again = input("\t\t Please choose a option 'S' or 'E' ")

    while start_again != "S" and start_again != "E":
        # can simplify: while start_again not in 'SE':
        start_again = input("You must enter a upper case letter" +
                "'S' or 'E' to continue")

    if start_again == "S":
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    """ Main loop for playing the game. """
    play_again = True
    while play_again:
        play_again = play_game()

    print("Thanks for playing the number game. Goodbye")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I am not very good with functions and interlinking them together. Your way is far superior to what i am doing.

Comment: Thankyou for your help, I am very appreicative. I am not very good with functions as i am a beginner and only been doing it for two days and would love to see how this is done. I struggle to see how i interlink them all. You would help me millions if you made it work so i can see fully how you do it and i can then fully grasp how this is done. Thank you.

Comment: I would be glad to.  I will edit the answer and fill it in using your code as much as possible... it will take me a few though. :)

Comment: I structured it a bit keeping your code as much as I could.  I adjusted a few other things like spacing/line length as I went.  Hope that helps show the concept of calling the play_game function.

Comment: This would help me out a lot, very grateful for your support.

Comment: Hey thanks man really, i am gonna be up all night dissecting this. Your awesome. Thank you so much, this is gonna really help. I have been @ this since 8 this morning : )

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a primer in how Python indentation works.

```
number = 1
while number < 10:
    print(number)
    number += 1
    print("this will print everytime because it's inside the while")

Output:

1
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
2
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
3
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
4
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
5
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
6
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
7
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
8
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
9
this will print everytime because it's inside the while
```

Notice that the second print prints every time because of it's indentation.
Now the second example:

```
number = 1
while number < 10:
    print(number)
    number += 1
print("this will print AFTER the loop ends")
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
this will print AFTER the loop ends
```

See how it only printed after the loop ended? That is because of the indentation. You should correct your code and indent it properly...

Ok, I corrected the code and it seems to be working now. Most of it was because of the indentation. Please try to understand how it works...

```
import random 

def is_same(targ, num):
    if targ == num:
        result="WIN"
    elif targ > num:
        result="LOW"
    else:
        result="HIGH"
    return result #this was out indented


User_Name = input("What is your name?\n:")
print("\nWelcome", User_Name, "To the guessing number game")
print( """\n\n
            GUESSING NUMBER GAME
      ----------------------------------
      ##################################
      #                                #
      #     [E] For Easy 1 - 10        #
      #                                #
      #     [M] For Medium 1 - 50      #
      #                                #
      #     [H] For Hard 1 - 100       #
      #                                #
      ##################################
      """ )
Choose_Level = input("\t\tPlease choose your Level : " )

while Choose_Level != "E" and Choose_Level != "M" and Choose_Level != "H":
    Choose_Level = input("Sorry. You must type in one of the letters 'E', 'M', 'H'\n:")

if Choose_Level == "E":
    print("You have chosen the Easy Level! You are a wimp by nature")
elif Choose_Level == "M":
    print("You have chosen the Medium Level! Can you defeat the game?")
else:
    print("You have chosen the Hard Level! You are a guessing number warrior")

if Choose_Level == "E":
    computer_number = random.randint(1,10)
elif Choose_Level == "M":
    computer_number = random.randint(1,50)
else:
    computer_number = random.randint(1,100)

guess = int(input("Can you guess the number? \n:"))



higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess)

counter = 1


while higher_or_lower != "WIN":
    counter +=1
    if higher_or_lower == "LOW":
        print("Guess attempts", counter)
        guess = int(input("\nSorry, you are to low. Please try again.\n:"))
    else:
        print("Guess attempts", counter)
        guess = int(input("\nSorry, To high. Please try again. \n:"))
    higher_or_lower = is_same(computer_number, guess) # this was out indented
print("Correct!\nWell done\n\n") # this all the way to the bottom was out indented
print( """
##############################
#                            #
#    [S] Play again          #
#                            #
#    [E] Exit                #
#                            #
##############################
""")

start_again = (input("\t\t Please choose a option 'S' or 'E' "))


while start_again != "S" and start_again != "E":
    start_again = (input("You must enter a upper case letter 'S' or 'E' to continue"))

if start_again == "S":
    done = False
else:
    print("Thanks for playing the awesome number game. Goodbye")
    done = True
```

Comment: Thankyou, i am understanding the indentation now. But if i need to go to the top how do i create a loop to get me back to the beginning of the game? if start_again == "S": loop back to the beginning? This will help me understand how the loop structure completely works.

Comment: You can put everything inside  a while loop if you'd like... Like while done == True.

You should try to divide your code in more functions though, it would be a lot better.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping. How do i put it all in a while loop i declare the variable 'done' to = false and then put the while done == False: below. I then import random below that but then fail and get a error mes saying random is not defined. I am not very good with functions. I kind of get it but wouldnt know what segments of code to break up and then interlink them together. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi, I have gone through your examples on how indentation works properly this morning and had the eureka moment! I now fully understand how indentation works. It really is not that hard! to understand : ) You explained it perfectly. Thankyou.